# How to join list elements to a path with python and pathlib?

Tags: python-3.x, pathlib

Assuming I have a list of unknown length. How would I join all elements of this list to my current path using pathlib?

```
from pathlib import Path

Path.joinpath(Path(os.getcwd()).parents[1] , *["preprocessing", "raw data"])
```

This is not working because the function expects strings not tuples.

Comment: Is ``"current_path"`` the current working directory, or some actual path?

Comment: it is the working directory but one step backwards: Path(os.getcwd()).parents[1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `pathlib.Path` constructor directly takes multiple arguments:

```py
>>> Path("current_path" , *["preprocessing", "raw data"])
PosixPath('current_path/preprocessing/raw data')
```

Use `Path.joinpath` only if you already have a pre-existing base path:

```py
>>> base = Path("current_path")
>>> base.joinpath(*["preprocessing", "raw data"])
PosixPath('current_path/preprocessing/raw data')
```

For example, to get the path relative to "the working directory but one step backwards":

```py
>>> base = Path.cwd().parent
>>> base.joinpath(*["preprocessing", "raw data"])
PosixPath('/Users/preprocessing/raw data')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works when the joinpath function is called on the base variable like you did above. :)